# understanding the basic codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH', ''))
    exit('no direct script access allowed');

class Hello extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {

        echo "this is my index function";
    }

    public function one() {
        $this->load->view('one');
    }

}

?>
```

I am the new user of codeIgniter.First i download code igniter software,then place it to the xampp/htdocs.Then i create a simple codeIgniter code which are show in the above.I don't understand where this code is to be save.I save this code in the Codeignitor/appilication.but it give me the below answer:

no direct script access allowed

What are the fault.please help me anyone.

Comment: Read documentation for controllers here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/) of Codeigniter? This is your Controller code and it should be placed inside `appilication/controllers` folder by name `hello.php`. See [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html).

Answer (score 0):

Before starting of any framework it would be good if you understanding directory structure, and what is the role of files.

Where should keep HTML, CSS, JS and logic and model part.

As you creating controller then it should save under

```
 application/controllers/ControllerName.php
```

[Here is the guideline for controller](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)

Also refer tutorials

http://tutorialcodeigniter.com
 http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-basic-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Open config.php within CodeIgniter\system\application\config.

```
Change base site url http://localhost/foldername
```